# What can I do if I don't receive the email for account authentication?

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I started Guild Wars 2, I received the following screen in the launcher:

[image: Email Authentication]

This appears to be waiting for a response to an email in order to verify authentication.

What can I do if I do not receive this email?

Comment: I've never not got one, but then I changed to the mobile authenticator instead.

Comment: I'm getting this screen from the client, and when I went to the site to login - also did not get a mail.  Checked twitter https://twitter.com/GuildWars2/status/279775335116050432 and apparently they are in the middle of patching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to check your spam inbox?

Sometimes e-mails can be redirected to it if the server thinks it is a spam.

Also, you could [login in the Guild Wars website](https://account.guildwars2.com/login?redirect_uri=https://www.guildwars2.com/en/) and check if your e-mail is correctly filled.

Comment: Logging into the website requires the same authentication - once this prompt pops up in the launcher, you will get an additional email (invalidating the one for the launcher) if you try and log into the website as well. My problem was that the email took ~20 minutes to arrive, which meant I was unable to start the game during this time.

Comment: Ouch. Using GMail they were pretty much instantaneous for me.

Comment: What e-mail client do you use? Do you access it in the web or in your computer (in a program like Outlook)?

As of @DavidYell, my Gmail is instantaneous for me too.

Comment: I'm using gmail as well, but out of the ~3 times I've had to do this the email has only arrives instantaneously for me once. The other ~two instances have resulted in a wait long enough for the client to timeout, followed by a second wait for another code when I next start it.

Comment: @pixel This seems like a problem in your client, this may be foolish from my part, but perhaps if the problem persist, you could reinstall the game (I believe your client is not sending the data to the server saying "Send me an authorization e-mail plesae").

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Eduardo, it is worthwhile checking your spam folders to ensure that the email hasn't been captured by any spam checkers your email providers use, however in my instance of the problem, the actual issue was impatience.

This is simply a case of waiting it out - you will receive an email eventually, but the Guild Wars 2 launcher will time out within a minute or so, this could potentially mean that leaving email authentication enabled could mean that during peak times you can't access the game.

Logging into the [Guild Wars 2 website](https://account.guildwars2.com/account) before providing this authentication will result in getting the same message but on the website, plus an additional code being sent out which invalidates the first code that the game client is waiting for;

[image]

If you do attempt to authenticate using a code in one of the earlier emails (ie: the game client email in order to access the website), you will get the following error;

[image]

At this stage, your game client is probably showing an error message and you still don't have access to the website, and you're going to have to start again. Opening *either* the game client or the website (not both) and waiting for an authentication email to arrive.

Authenticating with either the game or the website will provide access to both until the next time your IP address changes.

If you come across this issue enough for it to be a problem, there is an alternative to using email authentication - by attaching a Google authenticator to your account you can disable email authentication and use Google authenticator in its place. *It is not possible at this time to disable email authentication without enabling the use of a mobile authenticator.*

To do this, simply log into the [Guild Wars 2 website](https://account.guildwars2.com/account), go to 'Security' and follow the on-screen instructions to set up the use of Google authenticator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following might be obvious, but it happened to me too many times:

If you happen to have multiple accounts on different e-mail addresses, 
be sure to check if you are looking at the right mail box. I have had that 'issue' many times (also with Steam accounts btw).